# ESP8266-01 Deep Sleep

Tags: esp8266

I have a question regarding the [ESP8266-01](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESP8266).

Do I need to solder a wire from GPIO16 to reset if I am using a button to wake the ESP module from deep-sleep mode ? Or is it needed only if the module must wake up by itself?

Comment: are you using nodeMCU?

Comment: No, it is a ESP8266-01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To wake up from ESP8266-01 from deep-sleep, you just have to send a low pulse on its RST pin.  GPIO16 is soldered to RST if you want to program and send a wake-up pulse using timers, which wakes up the ESP8266 periodically.

If you want to wake it up using switch, you don't need that. You just have to setup a simple momentary switch like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkCGFy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Yours explanation and schematic helped a lot.